# std::reference_wrapper/std::unique_ptr alternative for std::vector that stores polymorphic value

Tags: c++, vector, stl, polymorphism, move

I usually store objects in `std::vector` as value and use std::move to transfer ownership. The problem is that storing by value can cause slicing when used with polymorphic objects.

This blog: https://oopscenities.net/2012/08/09/reference_wrapper/ which shows that `std::vector` can be used to store polymorphic object in `std::vector`. Problem is that since `std::reference_wrapper` simply stores the reference to the object, the lifetime of the object must be guaranteed for the duration of `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<>>`'s life time.

eg:

```
class PolymorphicClass; //derived from SuperClass
namespace MyProject
{
    class MyClass
    {

    public:
        std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<SuperClass>> _member;
    };
}

int main()
{
    MyClass test;
    test._member.push_back(PolymorphicClass());
}
```

This wouldn't work. Instead of `std::reference_wrapper` I can use `std::unique_ptr` but I was wondering if there is another option.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends of the *ownership* the vector holds against its elements. If you want the vector to **own** them, the way to go is [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr).

If, otherwise, you want the vector to **share ownership** along with other system in your code, you could use [`shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).

If you don't want the vector to hold any ownership against the objects, but still be able to check if they have been deleted, the way to go would be [`weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr).
Take into account that the last 2 options require the objects to have been created using a `shared_ptr`, storing shared pointers that reference an object allocated in the stack (for example) would be nasty.

Comment: I did end up going with unique_ptr. I guess there is really no good way to handle polymorphism on non-heap memory-kinda ironic since vector allocates to heap with large enough size.